# Is there a way to return only the first word in a set

Tags: python

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn


def antonyms_for(word):
    antonyms = set()
    for ss in wn.synsets(word):
        for lemma in ss.lemmas():
            any_pos_antonyms = [ antonym.name() for antonym in lemma.antonyms() ]
            for antonym in any_pos_antonyms:
                antonym_synsets = wn.synsets(antonym)
                if wn.ADJ not in [ ss.pos() for ss in antonym_synsets ]:
                    continue
                antonyms.add(antonym)
    return antonyms

print(antonyms_for("bad"))
```

prints: `{'unregretful', 'good'}`

is there a way to print only the first word `{'unregretful', 'good'} -> {'unregretful'}`

Comment: Consistently, no.  Sets are by definition unordered. Perhaps a list or tuple structure (which support ordering and slicing) would better suit this case.

Comment: @GedasMiksenas - Neither will work as  sets do not support slicing, nor does the function return a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about the state of the set that's returned, you could use the method [`pop()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.pop) on it:

```
print(antonyms_for("bad").pop())
```

This will return ONE of the set items. There is no definitive notion of first in a set as they are unordered.

If you expect the first value in **alphabetical order** then you can use built-in function [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min):

```
print(min(antonyms_for("bad",default=None)))
```

[EDIT] To avoid getting an error from .pop() when the output set is empty, you can use `or {None}` in the statement:

```
print( (antonyms_for("bad") or {None}).pop() )
```

Comment: Note: if the underlying collection (here: set) is empty, the `pop()` method will raise a `KeyError`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iter`+`next`:

```
next(iter(antonyms_for("bad")))
```

output: `'good'` **or** `'unregretful'`

*Note that sets are **unordered**, so **there is no way to reliably obtain a given value**, it is not random either, you will just get what the hashing algorithm puts first in the python implementation that you are using.*

Answer (score 0):

[*Sets*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) are **unordered** collections (not sequences), so there is no *first* or *last*.

You can transform the iterable *set* to a [sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq), e.g. one of the following data structures

- *list*, using constructor `list(iterable)`
- *tuple*, using constructor `tuple(iterable)`

and then use [indexing](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) to obtain the first:

```
words_set = antonyms_for("bad")
if words_set:
   first_word = tuple(words_set)[0]
   print(f'First antonym: {first_word}')  # expected to print 'unregretful'
else:
   print('No antonym found!')
```

Since there may be cases with an empty set returned, you may test for the presence of any elements first using `if words_set:`.